# How do I configure JSHint with Adsafe?

Tags: javascript, jshint

Does anybody know how to configure JShint with the *safe* and *adsafe* options? I went through http://www.jshint.com/docs/ but didn't find anysuch option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers have removed the Adsafe dependency according to this link: https://github.com/jshint/jshint/issues/3.

Comment: Note that ADsafe functionality has since been [removed from JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/267939b9168419312782a8533e35c60243215d56) too, so your only option is to use an older version of JSLint (or a very old version of JSHint). Also, you can accept your own answer to the question. Doing so keeps the site clean and tidy as your question appears answered in search results.

Comment: Sure. However, I can only accept my own answer after 2 days. Also, I didn't actually know that it was deleted from JSLint too as I was using Notepad++ plugin for scanning it. I guess I need to contact the plugin's developer. :)

Comment: Yeah, it was a very recent change. It removed HTML and CSS validation too, although I don't think many people used that. The best option for plugins now is probably to offer a version switcher.